# Ask user to set react native app as default SMS handler

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, sms

My app has SOS feature that uses SMS permission to send SMS from app (without opening native Message application). I can't find a way how to call a prompt that will ask user to set app as default SMS handler. I need it because Google Play can't approve my app because app uses sensitive permission like SMS. Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

This is message from Google Play below:

> You declared default SMS handling in your declaration form, but your app isn’t the registered default handler for SMS or its other core functionality.